# Fresh install no drivers

Tags: drivers, graphics, 13.10

I installed Ubuntu 13.10 on my laptop (Acer Aspire E1 572G) I installed over my win 8.1 partition.

I just erased the disc, but while doing so I had control over my mouse and was able to connect to the wireless via the wireless symbol on the top right of the screen.

I think I wiped any drivers that were there though, I did the initial install in work and while doing so I was called out of the office and when I got back I saw a message saying,

```
The system is running in low graphics mode
Your screen, graphics card and, input device settings could not be detected 
correctly. You will need to configure these yourself.
```

Is there a way I can configure them?

Comment: Please tell me some detais so that i may be able to answer you.At first You installed your ubuntu o.s inside windows or in a separate drive . And the second thing is the low graphics warning are displayed in windows or ubuntu.

Comment: Ubuntu 13.10 has been EOL for years. We can help you better if you use a supported release of Ubuntu.

Answer (score 0):

Chances are that the install used very generic drivers which allowed the use of the devices and they are no longer being utilized. There's usually support for wired internet at the point you're at and is how I remedied this in the past. If you plug in an active ethernet cord and then search out **Additional Drivers** .. for me, using Xubuntu 12.04, it's in the Xubuntu Menu under settings but I believe in newer, Unity powered Ubuntu you can search out **Software Sources** and choose the "Additional Drivers" tab within that. The rest should be straight forward so long as you have some form of connectivity.

[EDIT] Since starting to type this, I see a comment saying you literally have no input control, either. If this truly is a brand new install, although I hate saying this, you may want to run the install again, with the wired connection in (assuming you have access to one).

Also, you will probably have to download from AMD to get your graphics up and running at full potential. See here: http://support.amd.com/en-us/download/desktop?os=Linux+x86#amd-catalyst-packages